# NHibernate's evict sending flush_all command to memcached servers

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, memcached

I've noticed that when I evict things from the session factory, the cmd_flush counter is increased in the memcached server.  This makes the caching less useful since it is reset fairly often.

Here's my code that triggers this:

```
session.SessionFactory.Evict(typeof(Foo));
session.SessionFactory.Evict(typeof(Bar));
session.SessionFactory.EvictQueries(key);
```

I haven't figured out how NHibernate turns this into a flush_all command yet.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to evict certain object types from the cache without blowing it all away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `SessionFactoryImpl.Evict` calls `Cache.Clear()` which calls `client.FlushAll()`.

I ended up tweaking the database design to avoid having to evict objects myself.